# How to update single data in entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to update only one data from my entity?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String token; //THIS
}
```

i want to update only token in my table, how can i do this with using repository or in different way?

Comment: Fetch the user by `id` then update `token` and `repo.save()`

Answer (score 0):

> By default the repository implementation will consider an entity new
>   if its `id`-property is `null`

You have to fetch the existing data by id to `userEntity` and set the token on this retrieved object. Then save this object using `repo.save(userEntity)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the repostiory interface:

**Method 1**
Load the user (findById).
Then set the token to the expected value (userEntity.setToken(token)) and use repository.save(userEntity).

**Method 2:**
Create a method on the repository interface. Annotate it with @Query("update JPQL/SQL statement here"). Do not forget to add @Modifying annotation too.

```
@Modifying
@Query("update UserEntity u set u.token= :token where u.id = :id")
void updateToken(@Param("token") String token, @Param("id") Long id);
```

**Method 3:**
Create an Impl to the repository interface, there you can use JPQL,SQL,Criteria API or any other methods.